# Abrir link em nova aba diretamente no arrayLink

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso aplicar o atributo `target=_blank` diretamente no array abaixo?

```
arrayLink[1]="https://url/cart.php?a=add&pid=00";
```

Não posso aplicar no HTML.

Segue função executada via onclick:

```
function buyVps(){
                var vpsDetails='Processor : '+arrayProcessor[sliderValue]+' GHZ'+'\nRAM : '+arrayRam[sliderValue]+' MB'+'\nRAID Storage : '+arrayStorage[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMySql Databases : '+arrayMySqlDB[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMonthly Price : '+'R$ '+arrayAmount[sliderValue];window.location.href=arrayLink[arrayBlocks[sliderValue]];
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `window.location.href` redireciona sua aba local para a nova url desejada. Para fazer o que você deseja, devemos utilizar a função `window.open`. Ficaria assim:

```
function buyVps(){
    var vpsDetails='Processor : '+arrayProcessor[sliderValue]+' GHZ'+'\nRAM : '+arrayRam[sliderValue]+' MB'+'\nRAID Storage : '+arrayStorage[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMySql Databases : '+arrayMySqlDB[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMonthly Price : '+'R$ '+arrayAmount[sliderValue];

    window.open(arrayLink[arrayBlocks[sliderValue]], '_blank');
};
```